# How do I use MQTTClient library on Arduino to publish and subscribe to the MQTT broker installed on a Mac using Homebrew?

Tags: objective-c, macos, mqtt, mosquitto, arduino-esp8266

I have create a MQTT system using MQTTClient library on my Arduino IDE for ESP8266 to publish and subscribe to io.Adafruit.  Everything is working great except there is some functionality that I can't get on an app I developed for my iPhone/iPad using MQTT.  So I have installed a Mosquitto broker on an old MacBook pro using Homebrew.  When I look at the Publish and Subscribe code for the broker on the MacBook it looks different than that I use on the Arduino and iPhone app.

```
//this is on the arduino using MQTTClient library
//connect
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);
//publish
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish temperature = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/temperature");
//subscribe
Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe trip2 = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/temperature");
```

On the local Mosquitto on MacBook I use this it subscribe

```
mosquitto_sub -t topic/state

//and this to publish

mosquitto_pub -t topic/state -m "hello World"
```

Is there a way to reconcile these so they work together?  Can someone recommend a book or website or tutorial that will help me do this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear as to what kind of answer you are looking for here (bearing in mind that requests for books etc are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here). Take a look at the [`mosquitto_sub` docs](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html); these will show you how to specify the server, username, password etc.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the info.  I have looked at the mosquitto_sub docs and think I am getting the hang of it.  However I can't seem to be able to change the topic -t.  Originally it says to use ```mosquitto_sub -t topic/state```.  That works ok but when I try to change to say topic/temp or feed/temp nothing happens.  Can someone show me how to change to topics and have more than one to subscribe to.  If you want me to start another thread I can.

Comment: It you want to subscribe to multiple topics then you need to specify this on the command like (e.g. `mosquitto_sub -t topic/state -t topic/temp -t feed/#`). If you subscribe to a topic and no messages are published on that topic then nothing will appear to happen (the program is just waiting for a message that never comes). You may benefit from reading an MQTT introduction (e.g. [steves](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt/), [Hives](https://www.hivemq.com/article/how-to-get-started-with-mqtt/)).

Comment: thanks that did it I finally figured it out with the help.  Not sure where I can put answered

Comment: Unfortunately you can't because there is no answer (just some comments). Please feel free to answer your own question if you feel it may help others (but the question does not really provide enough detail for someone else to answer it).